# android-download listview images where cursor stops

Tags: android, android-listview

I've a custom listview , each row has an imageview that downloads image from a server .
I'm using a cursoradapter , this is the code that download image:

```
private class downloadimage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        private Bitmap pic;
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> viewReference;

        public downloadimage(ImageView view) {
            viewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(view);
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... param) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(param[0]);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
                if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    try {
                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/thumb");
                        dir.mkdirs();
                        File file = new File(dir, param[1]);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
                        FileOutputStream f = null;
                        f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        if (f != null) {
                            f.write(bao.toByteArray());
                            f.flush();
                            f.close();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
            return pic;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }
            ImageView imageView = viewReference.get();
            if(bitmap!=null){
                if (imageView != null) imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

    }
```

it works , the problem is this, If I scroll listview alot ,it begin to download each item image and it could take a long time to download the current row image and meantime it may change the row imageview 2-3 times .
I want to stop downloading while scrolling and when scrollview stops , then it download all the images on the screen .

How can I do that ? I don't want to use libraries like "Android-Universal-Image-Loader" , because I download all the images and each image has an specific address ,I mean , I may have several sub directories on sd card for 1 image .

Could you help me ? 
thank you

Comment: you need persist your image, instead of insert your image into imageView store that in one property of your listItemClass and read from that, I think you need write you custom adapter for handling that

Comment: @shayanpourvatan  thanks for the reply , could you give me an example ?